# Deploy a .NET Core application with AppVeyor: file locked by external process (Appveyor agent)

Tags: deployment, appveyor, app-offline.htm

I'm trying to deploy a project on a server using Appveyor agent. However, If I donot not restart or stop application before deployment, it do not works.

```
Web Deploy cannot modify the file 'TestProject.Application.dll' on the destination because it is locked by an external process.  In order to allow the publish operation to succeed, you may need to either restart your application to release the lock, or use the AppOffline rule handler for .Net applications on your next publish attempt.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE.
```

Is there an easy way to work with an app_offline.htm file? appveyor.yml configuration using the "app_offline" feature do not work in this kind of environment.

I was looking for something in the "before/after" section. Here's my appveyor.yml:

```
version: '1.0.{build}'
os: Visual Studio 2015

install:
- "SET PATH=C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\bin;%PATH%"

branches:
  only:
  - master

assembly_info:
  patch: true
  file: '**\AssemblyInfo.*'
  assembly_version: '{version}'
  assembly_file_version: '{version}'
  assembly_informational_version: '{version}'

build_script:
- nuget sources add -name "VNext" -source https://dotnet.myget.org/F/cli-deps/api/v3/index.json
- nuget sources add -name "nugetv3" -source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
- dotnet restore
- dotnet build */*/project.json

after_build:
- ps: Remove-Item -Path src\TestProject.Web\web.config
- ps: Move-Item -Path src\TestProject.Web\web.$env:APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH.config -Destination src\TestProject.Web\web.config
- dotnet publish src\TestProject.Web\  --output %appveyor_build_folder%\publish 

artifacts: 
- path: .\publish 
  name: TestProject.Web 

test: off

deploy:
  - provider: Environment
    name: east-webhost
    artifact: TestProject.Web    
    remove_files: false
    on:
      branch: master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at [before/after deploy scripts](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/agent/#running-powershell-scripts-on-target-server-during-deployment). Also check [this sample](https://gist.github.com/IlyaFinkelshteyn/6ec4c814b81b16363254d860fcaac3f9) on how you can ensure that file released.

--ilya.

Comment: I have have my before-deploy.ps1 at the root of my project but it is not executed, any thought on this?

/deploy.ps1
/src/TestProject.WebApp

I included this deploy.ps1 in my solution as "Solution item".

Still nothing executed on the server.